# Parallel TestNG Results in IntelliJ are mixed up

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, testng

I am running tests in parallel with TestNG (v6.14.3, desclared as a dependeny in pom file) and IntelliJ (2018.1.1).

The tests are run on 3 browsers FF, Chrome and IE. I have some logs/println of test steps in the console, but the results are not quite clear, structure of result on each browser is a bit messed up, as following screenshot:

[image]

For example, when I choose test on Firefox, the output is empty, so I don't see my outputs. But when I click on the root BKMS_FileUpload, all outputs for all 3 browsers are there and mixed up, so it's hard to say what is what.

I expect that the ouputs should be printed separatedly for each browser. I don't know if I am missing something. This is my testng.xml

```
<suite name="BKMS_FileUpload" parallel="tests">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="ScreenShotListener" />
</listeners>
<test name="FileUpload Performance Test Firefox">
    <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>        
    <classes>
        <class name="FileUploadPerformanceTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="FileUpload Performance Test Chrome">
    <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>        
    <classes>
        <class name="FileUploadPerformanceTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="FileUpload Performance Test IE11">
    <parameter name="browser" value="IE" />        
    <classes>
        <class name="FileUploadPerformanceTest" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue with sample project?

Comment: @y.bedrov yes, the results are like this everytime since I run test in parallel. I just notice something else: when an assert on a browser, ex. Firefox, failed, there is no exception thrown, and the icon "green tick" is still shown for that test.

Comment: I also have the same problem when it comes to parallel execution. Parent child hierarchi is messed up. It's your Login Test are failed, but there are payment tests under it. I cannot solved this problem in IntelliJ.

Comment: Could you please report an issue on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. attaching project example?